# SELECT MAX RANK INCLUDING NULLS

Tags: sql, t-sql, max, dense-rank

I'm trying to select the `MAX` ranking from the rows returned whilst at the same time including the row/s which contains NULL values in the `Award Date` field. How would I go about this ?

```
SELECT 
    V.Name
    ,Selected
    ,SRV.SBID
    ,SRV.DateCreated
    ,SRV.Version
    ,[Awarded] = ARW.DateCreated 
    ,[Rank] = CASE WHEN ARW.DateCreated IS NOT NULL THEN DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY SRV.SBID ORDER BY ARW.DateCreated ) ELSE 0 END
FROM SRV
LEFT JOIN ARW ON ARW = SRV.ID
LEFT JOIN V   ON V.ID = SRV.VALUE
WHERE SRV.SBID = 767
```

CURRENT OUTPUT:

```
Name   Selected ID  Date                   Num  Award Date             Rank
AM Demo     1   767 2020-01-09 14:39:25.180 3   NULL                    0
Ven Two     1   767 2020-01-09 14:39:26.383 3   2020-01-09 14:42:23.677 2
Ven Two     1   767 2020-01-09 14:39:26.383 3   2020-01-15 14:41:05.680 3
```

REQUIRED OUTPUT:

```
Name   Selected ID  Date                   Num  Award Date             Rank
AM Demo     1   767 2020-01-09 14:39:25.180 3   NULL                    0
Ven Two     1   767 2020-01-09 14:39:26.383 3   2020-01-15 14:41:05.680 3
```

Comment: You state you want to exclude rows that contains null but your required output still has a row with null in it am I missing something here??

Comment: @MattDouhan sorry I meant include, i've edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add one more field in your query:

```
 ,[Rank2] = CASE 
              WHEN ARW.DateCreated IS NOT NULL 
                     THEN DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY SRV.SBID 
                                             ORDER BY ARW.DateCreated DESC) 
              ELSE 0 
            END
```

Then, in an outer query, select row with `Rank2 IN (0,1)`

Comment: Awarded this one as its more efficient and requires less code

Answer (score 1):

You could use a row number to get rid of the duplicates

```
with mydata as
(
*your query here*
),
rankgen as
(
select mydata.*, row_number() over(partition by Name order by rank desc) rn
from mydata
)
select *
from rankgen 
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Isn't this going to exclude the `NULL` values?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos It doesn't exclude `NULL` values, I've tested it